# Prevent down arrow or up arrow from updating a combo box in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Often when a user sees results from search string results in a combobox dropdown, a natural response is to arrow down to a result they pinpoint.

But, if my users click the down arrow, it will update the combobox, thereby not jumping to the record as expected.  I'd like to limit the combobox to sense an update ONLY if the user hits "Tab", "Enter" or a Mouse click.

The combo box search that I've written otherwise works perfectly.

Here's my code in the On Key Up event

```
Private Sub cboGCPC_Search_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  Dim strSQL As String

        strSQL = "SELECT * " _
               & "FROM qryGCPC_Search " _
               & "WHERE [DocumentNumber] Like '*" & Me.cboGCPC_Search.text & "*' OR [Description] Like '*" & Me.cboGCPC_Search.text & "*' OR [Vendor] Like '*" & Me.cboGCPC_Search.text & "*' OR [Receiver] Like '*" & Me.cboGCPC_Search.text & "*';"


 Debug.Print strSQL

        Me.cboGCPC_Search.RowSource = strSQL
        Me.cboGCPC_Search.Dropdown

End Sub
```

Comment: I think i know what you're getting at but it's a little unclear what you mean by 'updating'. "if my users click the down arrow, it will update the combobox," "limit the combobox to sense an update ONLY...". the cbo is updating with every keystroke isn't it? What happens on "Tab", "Enter" or a Mouse click?

Comment: To clarify, I'm referring to the keystroke that would cause "lose focus" of the combo box.  As soon as the focus is lost, the combo box is considered updated.  This in turn fires the AfterUpdate event.  While the user is typing in the "key up event" the combo box is not yet in stone. But when the user clicks the down arrow, (or enter or tab, or clicks the mouse) the combo box *IS* considered updated because it loses focus of the combo box.  There must be a way to trap the down arrow key or the up arrow key from causing the AfterUpdate event to fire as the user scans with the up or down keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
Private Sub cboGCPC_Search_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 38 Then
        KeyCode = 0
        'Me.Combo0.Dropdown 'try this too, if necessary.
        'Exit Sub           'try this too, if necessary.
    End If
    If KeyCode = 40 Then
        KeyCode = 0
        'Me.Combo0.Dropdown 'try this too, if necessary.
        'Exit Sub           'try this too, if necessary.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 38 is up arrow, 40 is down arrow. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Precisely.  Thank you very much.  I added the how I implemented it.

Comment: There is one small glitch. I didn't notice it yesterday.  After the user selects a value, it does fire the AfterUpdate, but the combo box stays dropped down.  I obviously need to isolate the Enter, Tab or Mouse click to be the only keys to fire the AfterUpdate AND close the dropdown.  Not sure how to close it.  I assumed firing the AfterUpdate closed the dropdown.

Comment: Ok, so the final answer is now displayed in "This is the way I implemented WAZZ's answer.  I added  "Case 1, 9, 13"  which effectively makes sure the Key Up event is finished when the user clicks the mouse (1),  Tab (9), or Enter (13).   Wazz originally says 'Try this' in his comments.  BOTH turned out to be necessary but in different cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete way I implemented WAZZ's answer.

```
Private Sub cboGCPC_Search_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  Dim strSQL As String

        strSQL = "SELECT * " _
               & "FROM qryGCPC_Search " _
               & "WHERE [DocumentNumber] Like '*" & Me.cboGCPC_Search.text & "*' OR [Description] Like '*" & Me.cboGCPC_Search.text & "*' OR [Vendor] Like '*" & Me.cboGCPC_Search.text & "*' OR [Receiver] Like '*" & Me.cboGCPC_Search.text & "*';"


    Debug.Print strSQL


        Select Case KeyCode

        Case 38, 40

            KeyCode = 0

    Case 1, 9, 13
            Exit Sub

        Case Else
            Me.cboGCPC_Search.RowSource = strSQL
            Me.cboGCPC_Search.Dropdown

        End Select


End Sub
```